# Button function interferes with input fucntion

Tags: javascript, html, dom, button, events

I'm creating a list where i can add and remove items. I have managed to add new items, but when i add a function to the delete button it makes the submit form fail. After i added the `btn.addEventListener("click", runEvent)` The `form.addEventListener("submit", addItem);` stopped working

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="main" class="card card-body">
        <h2 class="title">Add Items</h2>
        <form id="addForm" class="form-inline mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="item">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <h2 class="title">Items</h2>
        <ul id="items" class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">Item 1 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete">X</button></li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item 2 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete">X</button></li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item 3 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete">X</button></li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item 4 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete">X</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
let form = document.getElementById("addForm")
let itemList = document.getElementById("items")

let btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete")

btn.addEventListener("click", runEvent)

function runEvent(event){

    event.preventDefault()
    console.log("hi")
}

// Form submit event
form.addEventListener("submit", addItem);

// Add item
function addItem(e){

    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(e)

    // Get input value

    let newItem = document.getElementById("item").value

    // Create new li
    let newLI = document.createElement("li")
    // Add class

    newLI.className = "list-group-item"
    // Add text node with input

    newLI.textContent = newItem

    //Delete button

    let button = document.createElement("button")
    button.className = "btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete"
    button.textContent = "X"
    newLI.appendChild(button)

    itemList.appendChild(newLI)
    document.getElementById("item").value = ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first you have to close each line in your JS with `;` then as long as you're selecting more than one element you need to define which button you need to use with your JS
as long as you're setting the same statement for all buttons, so i used `querySelectorAll()` to select all buttons and used for to loop with all results,
try the snippet. wishing you goodluck achieving your aims.

```js
let form = document.getElementById("addForm");
let itemList = document.getElementById("items");

let btn = document.querySelectorAll(".delete");
for (var i =0; i<btn.length ; i++) {

btn[i].addEventListener("click", function runEvent(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("hi");
});
}







// Form submit event
form.addEventListener("submit", addItem);

// Add item
function addItem(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);

    // Get input value

    let newItem = document.getElementById("item").value;

    // Create new li
    let newLI = document.createElement("li");
    // Add class

    newLI.className = "list-group-item";
    // Add text node with input

    newLI.textContent = newItem;

    //Delete button

    let button = document.createElement("button");
    button.className = "btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete";
    button.textContent = "X";
    newLI.appendChild(button);

    itemList.appendChild(newLI);
    document.getElementById("item").value = "";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div id="main" class="card card-body">
    <h2 class="title">Add Items</h2>
    <form id="addForm" class="form-inline mb-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="item">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <h2 class="title">Items</h2>
    <ul id="items" class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item">Item 1 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete">X</button></li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Item 2 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete">X</button></li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Item 3 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete">X</button></li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Item 4 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete">X</button></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer before mine is good and all but it cannot run a function when the delete button of a new element that was added is clicked this was because no eventListener or onclick was added to the button of the added element. so i made that work.

I also made it so that the item is removed when the delete button is clicked.

you can run the snippet and check

```js
let form = document.getElementById("addForm");
let itemList = document.getElementById("items");

function runEvent(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  itemList.removeChild(event.target.parentNode)
};

let btn = document.querySelectorAll(".delete");
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {

  btn[i].addEventListener("click", () => runEvent(event));
}







// Form submit event
form.addEventListener("submit", addItem);

// Add item
function addItem(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  // Get input value

  let newItem = document.getElementById("item").value;

  // Create new li
  let newLI = document.createElement("li");
  // Add class

  newLI.className = "list-group-item";
  // Add text node with input

  newLI.textContent = newItem;

  //Delete button

  let button = document.createElement("button");
  button.className = "btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete";
  button.textContent = "X";
  button.addEventListener('click', () => runEvent(event))
  newLI.appendChild(button);

  itemList.appendChild(newLI);
  document.getElementById("item").value = "";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="main" class="card card-body">
    <h2 class="title">Add Items</h2>
    <form id="addForm" class="form-inline mb-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="item">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <h2 class="title">Items</h2>
    <ul id="items" class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item">Item 1 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete">X</button></li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Item 2 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete">X</button></li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Item 3 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete">X</button></li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Item 4 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete">X</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

hope this helped